# Can someone give a numerical example for the definition of a field?

Tags: probability, definition, sigma-algebra

This is the definition for a field of events from a lecture slide:

Let $\Omega$ be a set, $\mathcal{A}$ $\subset$ $P(\Omega)$ with the power set $P(\Omega)$.

$\mathcal{A}$ ist called field (of events) on $\Omega$ if the following three properties hold:

(i) $\Omega \in \mathcal{A},$

(ii) $ A\in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow \bar{A} \in \mathcal{A} $

(iii) $A,B \in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow A \cup B \in \mathcal{A}$

Comment: When you toss a coin the outcomes can he 'head' (H) or 'tail' (T), so $\Omega=\{H,T\}$ and a field $\mathcal{A}$ is $\{ \emptyset, \{H\}, \{T\}, \{H,T\}\}$

Comment: Thanks! So if $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ a field $\mathcal{A}$ is $\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ right?

Comment: This $\mathcal{A}$ fullfills the three properties so it is a field.

Answer (score 2):

Reproducing comments:

Denote 
$$
\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\} \\
$$
By the properties defined in the post, you can verify that
$$
\mathcal{A} = \{ \emptyset, \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,2,3,4\} \}
$$
is a sigma-algebra wrt $\Omega$.